# Nestes MsAccess SQL FROM query

Tags: ms-access, split, nested, substring

I got a ms access database with a table named Events

```
AlarmID | Model | Landscape | Date | EventHandle | EventDescription
```

The EventDescription content looks like this in text:

```
Host_systemEDGE ma 05 jan, 2015 - 15:33:16 - Server Server1   System Eventlog Event Source = Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog Event Description = [23] The event logging service encountered an e
```

I want to find the count of unique EventDescriptions. but the Servername (Server Server1) is different almost every time. the idea was to split on the "=" or " = [" character. and just display everything behind it so the count doesn't split on the date, time or server text

First I tried this:

```
SELECT COUNT(cd.EventDescription) AS AantalUniekeMeldingen, cd.EventDescription 
FROM (SELECT EventDescription, [Date], Eventhandle  FROM Events) AS cd 
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN #1-1-2014# AND #7-1-2015# AND Eventhandle LIKE 'MONITOR MATCH EVENT%' AND EventDescription LIKE '%[[]%' AND EventDescription LIKE  '%[]]%' 
GROUP BY cd.EventDescription
ORDER BY COUNT(cd.EventDescription) DESC
```

Tried to convert it to:

```
SELECT COUNT(cd.EventDesc) AS AantalUniekeMeldingen, cd.EventDesc 

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ab.EventDesc, ab.[Date], ab.Eventhandle FROM (SELECT MID(EventDescription, instr(1," = ")) AS EventDesc, [Date], Eventhandle AS ab FROM Events) AS cd 

WHERE [Date] BETWEEN #1-1-2014# AND #7-1-2015# AND Eventhandle LIKE 'MONITOR MATCH EVENT%' AND EventDescription LIKE '%[[]%' AND EventDescription LIKE  '%[]]%' 
GROUP BY cd.EventDescription
```

Is there any easier way? Substring didn't worked...

results needs to look like:

```
Count | Desc
2     | [1]abcd-abcd..
1     | [2]abd-abd..
```

not like this:

```
Count | Desc
1     | 16:20 [1]abcd-abcd..
1     | 16:02 [1]abcd-abcd..
1     | 13:37 [2]abd-abd..
```

Comment: I can provide a small sample DB if needed

Comment: I know the fastest way would be to create a better database, or format it in the program code instead of the query. But in the current setting here that isn't possible